# Getting white border on UIView when applying border Width and border Color

Tags: ios, objective-c, border

I am working on collage app and in collage view I need to set border width and corner radius of frame, the view will be a sublayer of another view and the back view will have background colour as brown.I am able to change the border width and corner radius using slider but after doing that I am getting small tiny border white line (like a shadow) around the view.I tried using shadow opacity but it didn't work. below is my code.

```js
- (IBAction)sliderActionToChangeCornerWidthOfView:(id)sender {
    
    UISlider *slider = (UISlider*)sender;
    
    
    int i=0;
    
    for (CollageView *viewCollage in self.collageView.subviews) {
        
        if ([viewCollage isKindOfClass:[CollageView class]]) {
            
            
            self.appDelg.borderWidth = slider.value/2;

            if ([[array objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"path"]!=nil) {
                
                
                
                if (arrayOfLayers.count > 0) {
                    
                    [arrayOfLayers makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperlayer)];

                }

                NSMutableArray   *arrayToRadius = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                arrayToRadius = [arrayToRadius getArrayOfCollages:_collageView.bounds.size numberOfCollages:numberOfCollages];
                NSArray *arrayToChangeCornerRadius=[[[arrayToRadius objectAtIndex:btnClickIndex] valueForKey:@"values"] objectAtIndex:0];
                
                UIBezierPath *starPath=[[arrayToChangeCornerRadius objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"path"];
                
                
                CAShapeLayer *cornerMaskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
                [cornerMaskLayer setPath:starPath.CGPath];
                viewCollage.layer.mask = cornerMaskLayer;
                CAShapeLayer *strokeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
                strokeLayer.path = starPath.CGPath;
                strokeLayer.lineWidth = self.appDelg.borderWidth;
                
                strokeLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound;
                // the stroke splits the width evenly inside and outside,
                strokeLayer.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
                
                if (patternImage!=nil) {
                    strokeLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[self patterDraw]].CGColor;

                }
                else
                {
                    strokeLayer.strokeColor = borderColour.CGColor;

                }
                CGRect rect=CGPathGetBoundingBox(starPath.CGPath);
                [viewCollage layoutIfNeeded];
                
                strokeLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.0;
                [arrayOfLayers addObject:strokeLayer];
            
                [viewCollage.layer addSublayer:strokeLayer];

                NSLog(@"value : %@", NSStringFromCGRect(viewCollage.frame) );
                
            }
            else
            {
                
                if (patternImage!=nil) {
                    viewCollage.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[self patterDraw]].CGColor;
                    
                }
                else
                {
                    viewCollage.layer.borderColor = borderColour.CGColor;
                    
                }
                
                viewCollage.layer.borderWidth = slider.value/2;


            }
            
            
            i++;   
        }
    }

    
}
- (IBAction)sliderActionToChangeCornerRadius:(id)sender {
    UISlider *slider = (UISlider*)sender;

    
    
    int i = 0;


    
    for (CollageView *viewCollage in self.collageView.subviews) {
        
        if ([viewCollage isKindOfClass:[CollageView class]]) {
            
            self.appDelg.cornerRadiusValue = slider.value;

            
            if ([[array objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"path"]!=nil) {

                
                if (arrayOfLayers.count > 0) {
                    
                    [arrayOfLayers makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperlayer)];
                    
                }
                
                NSMutableArray   *arrayToRadius = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                arrayToRadius = [arrayToRadius getArrayOfCollages:_collageView.bounds.size numberOfCollages:numberOfCollages];
                NSArray *arrayToChangeCornerRadius=[[[arrayToRadius objectAtIndex:btnClickIndex] valueForKey:@"values"] objectAtIndex:0];
                
                
                
                UIBezierPath *starPath=[[arrayToChangeCornerRadius objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"path"];
                CAShapeLayer *cornerMaskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
                [cornerMaskLayer setPath:starPath.CGPath];
                viewCollage.layer.mask = cornerMaskLayer;
                CAShapeLayer *strokeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
                strokeLayer.path = starPath.CGPath;
                strokeLayer.lineWidth = self.appDelg.borderWidth;
                
                strokeLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound;
                // the stroke splits the width evenly inside and outside,
                strokeLayer.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
                if (patternImage!=nil) {
                    strokeLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[self patterDraw]].CGColor;
                    
                }
                else
                {
                    strokeLayer.strokeColor = borderColour.CGColor;
                    
                }
                CGRect rect=CGPathGetBoundingBox(starPath.CGPath);
                [viewCollage layoutIfNeeded];
               
                
                
                

                [arrayOfLayers addObject:strokeLayer];
                [viewCollage.layer addSublayer:strokeLayer];
 
                
                
                
                NSLog(@"value : %@", NSStringFromCGRect(viewCollage.frame) );
                
            }
            
      else
            {
                viewCollage.layer.cornerRadius = slider.value;
            }
         
            
            
            i++;
            
        }
    }

    
}
```

Below is the screenshot of the issue which I am facing

[image: This is the issue]

Can anyone please help me on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can get angle of view by following code:-

```
CGFloat radians = atan2f(view.transform.b, view.transform.a);  
CGFloat degrees = radians * (180 / M_PI);
```

Can you try once by adding following line:-

**UIImageView.clipsToBounds to YES**

It will help to get radians and degrees of rotation of particular view.

Hope it works!

Comment: I am not rotating that view.that is not the issue. when I apply border colour with brown I am getting a white tiny line  around that view.Please check the screenshot(issue is marked with red arrow line).